# Animating items in GridView does not stop Android

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

Here is my requirement. Add content to a grid view from a web service and randomly apply fade-in animations to each grid item.At a time only a single grid item will be animated.

Here is my XML code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="0.1"
      android:toAlpha="1.0"
      android:duration="1000"
      android:repeatCount="1"
      />
</set>
```

I am calling the animations here:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void run() {
                                      /* do what you need to do */
                                       s=RandonNumberGenerator.randInt(0, arg0.getResult1().size()-1);
                                      flipCard(s);
                                      /* and here comes the "trick" */
                                      handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
                                   }
                                };
                                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

I am passing the randomly generated grid item index into my method.

```
public void flipCard(int x)
{
     zoomin.setAnimationListener((AnimationListener) this);
      View viewItem = dashboardgv.getChildAt(x);
      if (viewItem != null) {                 
         ImageView img = (ImageView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.db_image);
        s=x;
         TextView overlay=(TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.overlayText);
         overlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         overlay.setAnimation(zoomin);

         overlay.startAnimation(zoomin);


       zoomin.setRepeatCount(0);
       //  overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
}
```

Here is my animation listener:

```
@Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


@Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            animation.cancel();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // zoomin.setAnimationListener((AnimationListener) this);
         View viewItem = dashboardgv.getChildAt(s);
              if (viewItem != null) {                 
                 ImageView img = (ImageView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.db_image);
                 img.setAnimation(zoomout);
                 TextView overlay=(TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.overlayText);
                 overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              overlay.setAnimation(zoomout);
                img.startAnimation(zoomout);
                 overlay.startAnimation(zoomout);


              }
        }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          animation.cancel();
    }
```

Now, Its repeating the animation forever.For example if I have four grid items the fade-in animation inside each one keeps repeating forever.

Comment: remove `handler.postDelayed(this,1000);`

Comment: because you are running it after every second. Don't set the animation inside handler

Comment: @Blackbelt I tried, but now only 1 item gets animated. I want the items to get animated randomly forever..

Comment: @Apurva where should I set my animation then?

Comment: this is my tuto about **animating items in gridView** it can help u http://www.tutozone.info/2014/10/tutoriel-gridview-personnalise-android.html